# How can a puppy drop down while he is already laid?

Tags: meaning

But I hardly saw or heard these things, for I ran at once to my little darling, and snuggled close to it where it lay, and licked the blood, and it put its head against mine, whimpering softly, and I knew in my heart it was a comfort to it in its pain and trouble to feel its mother's touch, though it could not see me. Then it dropped down, presently, and its little velvet nose rested upon the floor, and it was still, and did not move any more

From a dog's tale by Mark Twain

Comment: I think it means 'dropped its head down', but can't be sure from this extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"dropped down" is **mostly** figurative. It means that he lost his liveliness, his vitality. The doggie is no longer animate (i.e. probably dead).

Comment: I'm not sure why this was voted down, so let me embolden "mostly".

Comment: +1 I hope they can provide a better answer soon.

Comment: Agreed. I agree that the dog physically lowered himself (more than he already was), btw. I thought that was obvious from my answer, for some reason.

Comment: It's kind of strange that once I voted your answer up, your answer became accepted almost at once. I don't what's wrong with my interpretation.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I was voted down at the same time you were. Someone is awful picky, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

If you have seen someone fell unconscious or passing away before, it would be easy to imagine that the whole body *sank*, literally, which is quite the same as *dropped down*.

When I read the passage, I can see that poor little thing *sank*, and lost his conscious, probably passed away.